# requirejs mocha context error

Tags: javascript, requirejs, mocha.js

I have a simple mocha test that fails when using requirejs and the `context` config.

Here's `A.js`

```
define([], function(){
    return {};
});
```

Here's the test `spec.js`

```
var requirejs = require('requirejs');

var localReq = requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "./",
    context: "context1"
})

describe("context test", function () {
    it("should not throw error", function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            console.log(localReq("A"), i);
        }
    });
});
```

When I run the test `mocha spec.js`, I get the following error:

Uncaught Error: Tried loading "A" at /Users/khirakawa/work/test/node_modules/mocha/bin/A.js then tried node's require("A") and it failed with error: Error: Cannot find module 'A'

Here's a screenshot:

[image: fail]

Notice how `A` was properly loaded and logged 100 times, yet the test still failed.  If I comment out the `context` config, it works just fine.

Mocha is also printing out '1 passing' and '1 failing', even though there is only 1 test.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

You could write your test like this:

```
describe("context test", function () {
    it("should not throw error", function (done) {
        localReq(["A"], function (f) { done(); });
    });
});
```

As you pointed out in a comment, calling `localReq` to get a module synchronously [should work](http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html#3) but for some unexplained reason it does not. The code above, which calls `localReq` to load the module asynchronously, works.

The reason Mocha is saying that your single test is passing and failing is that it is detecting an error that happens after your test is over and has no other test to associate it with. This kind of error message where the same test both passes and fails is a sure indication that you've got something happening asynchronously but that you have not taken care of it in your Mocha test setup.

Comment: Thanks Louis! Your explanation makes sense from a browser perspective.  What I don't understand in node-land is: 1) requirejs's docs state that "... when running in Node, module loading will be loaded using sync IO calls, and loader plugins should resolve calls to their load method synchronously."  It doesn't say anywhere that modules need to be loaded first. 2) My test case works if I use the default context of "_", and 3) If I change what is returned in A to be {test: "test"}, it will print {test: "test"} 100 times, suggesting that it was loaded synchronously.

Comment: You're right that my explanation as to why `require("A")` is failing is not on target. However, it is clear that what RequireJS *actually* does is not concordant with the documentation. Otherwise, your code would work. At this point, it looks like a bug to me.